# Problema con hover en CSS y HTML

Tags: css, html5, css3, web

Hola espero tengan un excelente día. Estoy empezando con css y html y en este momento estoy tratando de hacer una menú desplegable con hover, y agregarle estilo con css, quiero que al pasar el mouse cambie el color y se desplieguen los items pero no hay caso de que me funcione agradecería su ayuda y comprensión para saber en que estoy fallando. Gracias.

Este es el código hecho:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Menu</header>
    <nav  class="all">
        
            <a id="title" href="">
                <ul>Inicio
                    <li>Productos</li>
                    <li>Empleados</li>
                    <li>Nosotros</li>
                </ul></a>                       
                <a id="title" href="">
                    <ul>Contacto
                    <li>Mapa</li>
                    <li>Telefono</li>
                </ul></a>
            <a id="title" href="">
                <ul>FAQ</ul>
                </a>
            <a id="title" href="">
                <ul>Opiniones
                    <li>Sugerencias</li>
                    <li>Comentarios</li>
                </ul></a>
    </nav>

<style type="text/css">
    .all {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
 
 #title {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #F9B55C;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #191C26;
}
#title  ul : hover {
    background-color: #CC678B;
}
#title  ul > li {
    display: none;
}
#title > ul li : hover {
    display: block;
}
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Los id's deben ser únicos, sustituye usando una clase igual para todos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer tienes unos espaciados en el hover y el css no los detecta. Te recomiendo que los estilos que le diste a `#title` los pases a la etiqueta `ul`, así quedaría:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .all {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    }
 
     #title {

     text-decoration: none;
    
    
    } 
    #title ul{
     color: #191C26;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #F9B55C;
    }

    #title  ul:hover {
    background-color: #CC678B;
    }
    #title  ul > li {
    display: none;
    
    }
    #title  ul:hover > li {
    display: block;

    
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Gracias me fue de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Cambié un poco la forma en que estructuras tu html, por ejemplo:

```CSS
<a><ul>Title...</ul></a>
```

por

```CSS
<div>Title<ul>...</ul></div>
```

porque un elemento inline( <a/>) no debe tener un elemento block(<ul/>) como hijo. Tambien el elemento `<ul/>` es el que desapareceré en vez de los elemento `<li/>`.
Tambien cambié a todos los elmento que usan el mismo id:`<a id="title"/>` por `<div class="title"/>`. Porque el id está diseñado para ser unico. [Para mas información](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).
Tambien note lo mismo que dijo [Oswaldo Cuevas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/482193/205933) : Css no interpleta los espacio antes de nombrar el evento: X(`ul :hover`), X(`ul: hover`), Y(`ul:hover`).

Reestructure tambien tu CSS:

```CSS
/*Desaparecemos el elemento para que no se vea la lista de opciones.*/
#title ul{
    display:none;
}
/*Si precionamos #title haremos que el elemento tenga el color morado.*/
#title:hover{
    background-color: #CC678B;
}
/*Si precionamos #title modificaremos su hijo ul y haci haremos que aparesca.*/
#title:hover > ul {
    background-color: #F9B55C;
    display:block;
}
/*Como queremos que el elemento li seleccionado por el puntero cambie el color, le cambiamos display: block; por background-color: #44aFFF;*/
#title  ul li:hover {
    background-color: #44aFFF;
}
```

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>Menu</header>
        <nav class="all">
            <!--Quité los enlances y coloqué un div, recuerda un elemento inline no puede tener como hijo un elemento block.-->
            <div class="title">
                <!--Puse el titulo a fuera del ul.-->
                Inicio
                <ul>
                    <li>Productos</li>
                    <li>Empleados</li>
                    <li>Nosotros</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                Contacto
                <ul>
                    <li>Mapa</li>
                    <li>Telefono</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                FAQ
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                Opiniones
                <ul>
                    <li>Sugerencias</li>
                    <li>Comentarios</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <style type="text/css">
            .all {
                display: flex;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                list-style: none;
            }
            /*Nota display bloc, lo unico que hace es que el elemento se comporte como block, pero no lo transforma en block.*/
            .title {
                display: block;
                padding: 1em;
                background-color: #F9B55C;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #191C26;
            }
            /*Desaparecemos el elemento para que no se vea la lista de opciones.*/
            .title ul{
                display:none;
            }
            /*Si precionamos #title haremos que el elemento tenga el color morado.*/
            .title:hover{
                background-color: #CC678B;
            }
            /*Si precionamos #title modificaremos su hijo ul y haci haremos que aparesca.*/
            .title:hover > ul {
                background-color: #F9B55C;
                display:block;
            }
            /*Como queremos que el elemento li seleccionado por el puntero cambie el color, le cambiamos display: block; por background-color: #44aFFF;*/
            .title  ul li:hover {
                background-color: #44aFFF;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Espero que los comentarios sean suficientes para aclarar cualquier duda que tengas, pero si tiene mas dudas no dudes en preguntar.

### Update:

1. Antes no tome en cuenta que el codigo repetia el mismo id. Le pido gracias a: BetaM por ayudarme a ver algunos errores de esta respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por la info y aclaraciones me fueron de gran ayuda